# Javascript Closures and Variable Scope

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm extending my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002642/javascript-variable-scope-in-event-handler), because I still don't fully understand the concept of javascript closures.  Take a quick look at the following code, which will put two markers on a map.  (The code is slightly modified from my previous question).

```
var map = google.maps.somefunctoinstantiatemap();
var address = new Array();
address[0] = '1 Smith Street';
address[1] = '2 Smith Street';
function onpageload()
{
for(var rownum=0; rownum<address.length; rownum++)
{
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address[rownum]
    }, function(results, status) {
        geocodeCallBack(results,status,rownum)
    });
}
}

function geocodeCallBack(results, status, argnum)
{
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        title: 'arg: '+argnum+' addr:'+results[0].formatted_address
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: marker.title
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Ok, multiple choice....what is the result when user clicks on both markers?

1. first marker displays 'arg: 0 addr: 1 Smith Street' and second marker displays 'arg: 1 addr: 2 Smith Street'
2. first marker displays 'arg: 0 addr: 2 Smith Street' and second marker displays 'arg: 1 addr: 2 Smith Street'
3. first marker displays 'arg: 1 addr: 1 Smith Street' and second marker displays 'arg: 1 addr: 2 Smith Street'
4. first marker displays 'arg: 1 addr: 2 Smith Street' and second marker displays 'arg: 1 addr: 2 Smith Street'
5. first marker displays 'arg: undefined addr: undefined' and second marker display 'arg: undefined addr: undefined'

When I run the code, the answer is 3.   But I was expecting the answer to be either 4 or 5.  Why is it not 4 and why is it not 5?

Comment: I think that can't be your real code, not least because your `for` loop up top is looping *three*, not two, times. Also, you seem to have plucked a `map` variable out of nowhere (nowhere you show, anyway).

Comment: This is missing a ton of info.  "What is the result" of what?  You gave two functions with no calls to either function and you reference Markers without any explanation.  If anything this seems like a Google Maps, question, not a closures one.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - ok, i fixed up those errors...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be expecting the closure to close over something (which it does), but you're not using anything in particular that it closes over in it (like the loop index). The `argnum` value you get in your `geocodeCallBack` comes from Google (because you've defined `rownum` as the third argument to your anonymous function, [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the loop counter), it's nothing to do with your loop counter.

A few other points about that code:

<s>Your loop at the top is looping *three* times, not two. You have it going from `0` to `<= results.length`. `results.length` is `2`, and so that will loop with `rownum` values `0`, `1`, and `2`. You mean `< results.length`.</s> *(You've fixed this.)*

<s>There's no purpose to your anonymous function here:</s>

```
geocoder.geocode( {'address': address[rownum]}, function(results, status, rownum) {geocodeCallBack(results,status,rownum)});
```

...since all it does is pass on the arguments it receives. That can and probably should just be:

```
geocoder.geocode( {'address': address[rownum]}, geocodeCallBack);
```

...unless the signature of the function is wrong and you shouldn't be declaring all of those arguments to it.

**Edit**: Based on your comments below, I think you may want this:

```
geocoder.geocode( {'address': address[rownum]}, makeCallback(rownum));

function makeCallback(therow) {
    return function(results, status) {
        geocodeCallBack(results, status, therow);
    };
}
```

...or in your "real code" as you put it, where you're actually using that row number as part of a selector:

```
geocoder.geocode( {'address': address[rownum]}, makeCallback(rownum));

function makeCallback(therow) {
    return function(results, status) {
        geocodeCallBack(results, status, $('#row-' + therow).val());
    };
}
```

The `makeCallback` function creates a function to be the callback. The function it creates closes over the `therow` argument passed into `makeCallback`, which never changes, and so you get `therow` being `0` for the callback you create on the first loop, and `therow` being `1` for the callback you create on the second loop.

In terms of understanding closures, I've written up this post which I think you may find helpful: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) It goes into the mechanics of how closures work in some detail. And the title is no lie: They're *not* complicated, people tend to tie themselves up in knots because they *think* they're complicated, but they're not.

Comment: in my real code, I have something like this `geocoder.geocode( {'address': address[rownum]}, function(results, status) { geocodeCallBack(results,status, $('#row-'+rownum).val())}`.  The problem is that rownum seems to always be hte value 1.

Comment: @John: That value is coming from Google, it's nothing to do with your loop counter. You've declared `rownum` as the third argument the anonymous function accepts, so within the anonymous function, it's going to have whatever value Google passes to the callback as the third argument. Unless you're intentionally receiving that third argument, don't declare it. Then you won't be shadowing `rownum` -- and then you'll have the problem you expect, because by the time the function gets called, `rownum` will be `2`, not `0` or `1`.

Comment: While this was going to be my answer too, I can find no indication that the callback should pass a third argument.  The doc says it passes just the first 2.  Wonder if this is some undocumented parameter.

Comment: @T.J. - bah sorry, there shouldn't be any 3rd arg in the anonymous function. I just corrected the comment.

Comment: @John: I've updated the answer with what I think you're looking for.

Comment: Well I know it's an error in the code, but how is the value of the argument in the callback `1` and not undefined?  If that is in fact the output, it would imply that the callback is being passed a value of 1 for that third parameter.

Comment: sorry or allt he confusion, i also updated my question to remove the 3rd arg from the anonymous function

Comment: @kingjiv: Ah, I see what you mean. Yeah, presumably they're passing some third argument there.

Comment: Hey T.J. Your answer worked.  I'll read up on your article after work to.  In the meantime, I modified your code for an experiment.  I tried this `function makeCallback(therow){alert(results); function(results,status){/* some code */}}`.  My alert statement produced a ReferenceError.  But I KNOW results exists, because it is used properly in the anonymous function() declared in the line after.  Will your article explain that phenomenon too?

Comment: @John: There's no `results` symbol in scope in the `makeCallback` function. The `results` symbol we use within the anonymous function exists only within that function, it's one of its named arguments. `makeCallback` knows nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

geocode() is overriding the value of numrow when you declare it as a function parameter.

```
for(var rownum=0; rownum<=address.length; rownum++)
{
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': address[rownum]}, function(results, status) {geocodeCallBack(results,status,rownum)});
}
```

Try this instead, this way geocodeCallBack is sent the rownum that is declared in the forloop

The result should be first marker displays 'arg: 0 addr: 1 Smith Street' and second marker displays 'arg: 1 addr: 2 Smith Street'

Comment: If he does that, `geocodeCallback` will always see `2` as its third argument. Definitely not what the OP wants.